# How to get parameter from view in onclick function in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onclick

I have an Android app developed in Kotlin(in AndroidStudio). In each element of RecyclerView I have a button with onclickFunction and I want to use a value from that element's view (precisely: "id" column of database table row, which give data to that element of RecycleView, which I already put in invisible textView) but how can I access it in onclick function?

So for example, I have RecyclerView element for data from database with Id=0, so for it's button I want to pass this 0 as parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set a new click listener in `onBindViewHolder`, you can simply reference the id from the item for that row in the listener. But this allocates new near-identical listeners for every item, which can potentially cause little GC stutters when scrolling a list fast. You could instead set the view’s `tag` value to the ID. Then you can have a common listener for all list items.

```
// Can set this same listener instance for every view:
val listener = OnClickListener { view ->
    val id = view.tag as Int
    //...
}

// In onBindViewHolder
val id = //...
holder.myView.apply {
    tag = id 
    setOnClickListener(listener)
}
```

Comment: To make it clear this val listener I have to put just in my adapter class or in oncreate method or companion object?
Also after line with val I have call a function? And how to bind it to correct button? (I didn't precise earlier but I have two buttons - each with different function to call)
Also in onBindView I get "unresolved refference" for "it"

Comment: I would define the listener inside the Adapter since it is relying on view tags, which are not something you would want to expose outside of where you’re using them. The code I showed below shows how you bind it to your button in each list item. In this case I referred to it as `myView`. Sorry, I was treating it like `let` instead of `apply`. Just remove the `it.` from each line.

Comment: But wait, shouldn't it be rather holder.view.ButtonName.apply? (actually if You'd write `myButton` instead of `myView` it would be more descriptive)
Also If I want bind two different functions to two different buttons I should go with val listenerA, and val listenerB(with ), and then 
holder.view.ButtonA.apply{ 
tag = Id
onClickListener = listenerA}
And then the same for ButtonB (just with listenerB instead)
I'm unsure, because when I do that I get `unresolved refference` for `onClickListener`.

Comment: It’s just an example. I don’t know what view properties you put in your ViewHolder. I didn’t even know you were using buttons. It’s more common to set a click listener on the parent view of the whole list item. And since you have two buttons calling two different functions, then yes, I would make two different listeners.

Comment: Actually it would make more sense to set the listeners in the ViewHolder constructor than over and over agin by doing it in onBindViewHolder(), but I was keeping the explanation simple.

Comment: Maybe it would, but to get the correct id number I need also a position (I mean second parameter of onBindHolder method, I raname it so in my project) and I don't know how to how to get to it inside onCreateViewHolder. 

And I still have no idea how to solve that problem with `unresolved reference` on `onClickListener`. I tried with add `it.` or `this.` as prefix, but with no effect... maybe using `this.setOnClickliner(ListenerA)` would be better option? (For now it seems to work, but I can't fully test it yet as there are some other parts of my app, which need to be ready first)

Comment: Yes, it should be `setOnClickListener(listenerA)`. I had forgotten there's no `getOnClickListener()` in the Java source, so Kotlin doesn't convert it into a property.